# .Net Code signing for ViewFinity

Tags: .net, code-signing

My company uses ViewFinity to validate applications that are allowed to be run with Admin privileges.

I have a C# application that needs Admin privileges that will be distributed to every desktop within our corporation.  Therefore we need to create a rule within ViewFinity that authorizes this app.  We would like to validate the publisher of the app so it's not just some random application that someone renamed on their desktop.

We generated a Certificate using Microsoft Certificate Services, and I signed my application with that Certificate (pfx file).  This is not a self-signed application, this is a legit Certificate.

I can run the StrongName validation tool to verify that the application is valid.  I can view the Manifest and see the public key.  If I right click the executable and click properties I do not see the "Digital Signatures" tab, so apparently I've done something wrong.

When I run the application, ViewFinity does not see the author (or publisher) of the application.  What do I need to do so that ViewFinity can determine the publisher.  Shouldn't it be extracting that information from the Certificate?

Comment: Additional info:  If I Sign the ClickOnce manifest and publish that, I can see the publisher.  Singing the assembly (with the same pfx file) doesn't seem to work.  I'm signing by just checking the checkboxes on the Properties/Signing tab selecting my pfx file and typing in the password.  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was signing it by clicking the check box on the signing tab in Visual Studio.  That is not enough.  I still had to run the signtool console app.  Once I did that, I can actually see the "Digital Signatures" tab when I rightclick the exe and select properties.